# Auto refresh token and autologout in vue

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am beginner web developer.
I make my first project in Laravel and Vue. I need to make:

1. Auto-logout after 3 minutes - when user is inactive
2. Auto ping to my token (domain.com/api/refresh).

I try do it in a function in my main.js:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.href = "domain.com/logout";
}, 30000);
```

for refresh, but it's run only one time - when I page reload.

How can I make it? Please help me :)

Comment: How you detect if user is inactive or active ?

Comment: check out the `v-idle` component: `https://github.com/malekim/v-idle`. Simply do <v-idle @idle="logout()" />

Comment: <v-idle
  @idle="onidle"
  @remind="onremind"
  :loop="true"
  :reminders="[10, 15]"
  :wait="5"
  :duration="300" />
  methods: {
    onidle() {
      alert('You have been logged out');
    },
    onremind(time) {
      // alert seconds remaining to 00:00
      alert(time);
    }
  }

Comment: In which file I must add this code? I need this timeout in all app

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following events `mousemove`, `mousedown`, `keypress`, and `touchdown` to determine whether a user is active. You will need to functions to start the timer and reset it. The reset will be used for the aforementioned events.

In your main.js, do this:

```
const timeoutInMS = 180000; // 3 minutes -> 3 * 60 * 1000
let timeoutId;
  
function handleInactive() {
    // Here you want to logout a user and/or ping your token
}

function startTimer() { 
    // setTimeout returns an ID (can be used to start or clear a timer)
    timeoutId = setTimeout(handleInactive, timeoutInMS);
}

function resetTimer() { 
    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    startTimer();
}
 
function setupTimers () {
    document.addEventListener("keypress", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", resetTimer, false);
    document.addEventListener("touchmove", resetTimer, false);
     
    startTimer();
}
```

Then call `setupTimers` on page load.

**NOTE:** The above code is one way you could detect if a user is inactive.